# Please explain this audit

Tags: support, review-audits

Please explain this audit https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/8029205. The commentary says:

> STOP! Look and Listen.
>
> This was an audit, designed to see if you were paying attention. You didn't pass. This post has severe quality issues. It is abusive nonsense, noise, spam, blatantly off-topic or otherwise irredeemable – readers will find it offensive or repulsive rather than helpful. Please delete or recommend deletion when reviewing such posts.

The entire text of the item reads:

> If you don't want to port all tables data (for example you need to port just some base data in special tables) scripting options is not useful for you. In this case you'll have two options. First is using some third parties tools such as Red-Gate and Second way is writing the script by yourself. I prefer Second option because except the expensive price of most of them i want to run just little script for little delete, update and inserting purpose.

I see nothing 'offensive or repulsive' here.

Yet another crummy audit. Extremely crummy. Really this has got to stop.

Comment: "offensive or repulsive" is only a small part of that warning message. I'm sure some of the links were spam, which would explain it being an audit.

Comment: @KevinBrown The message says 'readers will find it offensive or repulsive'. This is simply untrue.

Comment: Honestly, the choice of what pieces of text were linked would have been my first clue.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET It *might* have been my first clue too, *if* I was looking for spam or merely trying to accumulate audit review points. There are just too many things wrong here. I've seen quite enough bad audits already but this one takes the cake, especiially in regards to the language used to describe the failure.

Comment: *always* look for spam, especially in late answers and VLQ. I've gotten bit by "clever" spam in the past as well, for what its worth.

Answer (score 27):

Look at the link destinations. It's spam.

Comment: So I'm being expected to check every link in an answer for spam? Seriously? And where is the part that 'readers will find offensive or repulsive'?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. That is an important part of reviewing.

Comment: Then I suggest those expectations are Olympian. I'm expected to infallibly detect correctly every audit question when I am merely casting a vote.

Comment: Also note that the text is simply stolen from another (non-deleted) answer to the same question. You should look *very* closely when reviewing very late answers posted by brand new accounts.

Comment: That information is not available when reviewing. All I saw was was I posted. If I am *also* expected to go back to the original question and check for duplicates then again the expectations are truly Olympian. This is broken.

Comment: You don't even have to visit the page to see that something is wrong - simply hovering over the links to see the URL shows that the destination (both point to the same place) has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: Agreed, *if* I was looking for spam and all the zillion other ways in which a post can be in violation and trying to be infallibe. I'm only casting a vote after all.

Comment: You *should* be looking for that in the review queue. If you don't want to, don't review.

Comment: Well if this is the nonsense I will continue to get, and which I've already had plenty of, I won't review. Enough is enough. If you don't want people to review, keep it up. It's woring.

Comment: @EJP we don't want people *who aren't going to do the whole job* to review. A user reviewing badly is worse than them not reviewing at all; if spam is reviewed as OK it could sit there for a while before being properly dealt with, which is bad for everyone. You're *"only casting a vote"* but if you aren't actually providing a robust review it's worse than no vote at all.

Comment: @EJP Well, then it seems we all do agree that the review audits indeed worked very well and as intended here.

Comment: The odd locations of those links alone should be a dead giveaway that this is spam without even having to check the URLs or deducing that the text was stolen.

Answer (score 23):

> The entire text of the item reads:

No, it didn't. You missed the two links to a site named "grandindia", which have absolutely NOTHING to do with the topic of the question or, indeed, the answer. Unless you have some good reason to believe such a URL is somehow relevant to SQL tooling, you wouldn't even have needed to *follow* those links; just hovering over them briefly with your cursor would've revealed the deception.

You also missed the sidebar, which we put there specifically to aid you in recognizing sketchy posts like this:

[image]

That "other answers" indicator - combined with the **irrelevant links** and **clearly truncated text** is a particularly good sign that there's something fishy going on; if you'd clicked through to the question, you'd have quickly observed that the rest of the text was **copied verbatim** from an existing answer.

This is a classic spammer technique. The intent of the audit was to teach you to recognize it. Please learn from it...

Comment: +1 for "The intent of the audit was to teach you to recognize it". The words "failing an audit" have come to feel like a terrible thing in our culture, but here on Stack Exchange, they just mean you are getting valuable feedback. Unless you are failing all your audits consistently, no one will even notice that it happened - they are not traps put there to expose you.

Answer (score -5):

I agree with user207421.  This type of request of a volunteer group is a bit much, and it's somewhat disheartening to be presented with this message when you were simply trying to do some good.  I think the amount of work it took to build these "audits" would probably have been better spent designing a question posting framework that guards against the kind of things that are being tested here.

At least a rewording of the "You've failed (and also suck)" message would be a good start.

Comment: Although some audits might be wrong (In which case one can post a question on Meta about it), the one discussed in this particular post is really obvious, although I don't particularly fancy the review queues either but if one is doing those catching such obvious spam should be a requirement.