# Should I avoid reviewing altogether?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, disputed-review-audits

I just failed another close vote audit.

This time it's this question: "[Is there a C++ compiler supporting concepts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30290240/is-there-a-c-compiler-supporting-concepts)" (I saw [this revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/30290240/2).)

How is this not "asking us to recommend or find a book, **tool**, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource"?  .... which is explicitly off-topic.

I can't click "I understand" on the audit dialog because I don't understand :(

Elsewhere in meta a senior person said "if you don't understand, you should stop reviewing".   Maybe that applies to me then?

Comment: LOL - does an upvote mean "yes, you should stop reviewing"?   I have to assume so eh?

Comment: FWIW: it means *"I have no idea why that question isn't a recommendation either and want someone to shed light on it because I don't have any answer either..."*

Comment: Let's agree on that :) Since this is a *discussion* question, an upvote means this is a good question worthy of *discussion*, and its not at all clear why the linked question isn't a close vote. A downvote means that it's a bad question, and for some reason its obvious why that linked question should not be closed. In the latter case, an answer explaining why would be great :)

Comment: `if you don't understand, you should stop reviewing` basically means *I've been here longer, look at my huge swinging package*. It's elitism at its finest, which you'll see every now and again on SO. You learn to read between the lines. The fact is, you're here attempting to better your understanding of the SO ecosystem, and as far as I'm concerned that's better than 100% of the robo-reviewers that scour the site.

Comment: I personally open all my CV queue posts in another tab and examine them there (unless it's painfully clear they're off-topic), so as to get a better picture.

Comment: @GreenAsJade I would be of the mind that an upvote here means that people appreciate your question, not that they're petitioning for you to quit reviewing. If you enjoy reviewing, and want to get some of the related badges or whathaveyou, keep at it. Ignore haters or learn from it if possible.

Comment: @royhowie Doesn't that seam wrong to you that you have to go to the post because you can't trust what you are seeing in the review queue?

Comment: Among other things, if you do disagree (and are sure) with an audit, remember to go to the question page manually and apply the close action (possibly -1 too) yourself. As I understand it this will remove, or help to remove, it from the automatically-built list of model posts (if it doesn't it should, and anyway it'll put it in the close queue for real and the q. will go away).

Comment: if you filter on a fairly narrow criteria the audits are really easy to *skip* because the are obvious they should have never been selected by the filter.

Comment: I've pretty much given up on reviewing for a similar reason. After reviewing over 4000 questions I encountered several posts I thought should be dealt with but, like you, was penalised for *broken* review audits. After getting banned from reviewing for 7 days, I then found myself in a pattern of opening the content in a new tab to see if it was actually closed before voting to close it - but this is obviously a bad thing to do as it goes against the point of reviewing anyway.

Comment: I didn't know you could get banned for failing audits.   I don't mind failing them,though its a little tiresome asking why too often.   But if I put all the effort in, then got banned... I'd sure be pissed.

Comment: tl;dr: Do not put too much emphasis on formal criteria.--There are too many false positives *and* at the same time false negatives among the (not) closed questions. Many questions (including the one in, well, question here) which receive close votes are interesting and constructive, although they may formally violate some criteria. Who cares. On the other hand my SO front page is full of an abundance of idiotic questions which are formally fine. Try to be sensible and let questions asked by qualified people stand if they are not completely OT.

Comment: Thanks to gurus who fixed my question after the original question was edited!

Comment: While I haven't completely stopped reviewing, I also review much less than I used to. Bogus audits are a big reason why.

Answer (score 80):

You got unlucky. It should indeed be closed with that reason, this has been taken care of by now.

Instead the question and answer got a bunch of upvotes, so the automated audit system thinks this is a good question. As long as it's an automated system, this kind of audit failure is unavoidable. Don't let it discourage you too much.

Comment: My unfortunate experience is that with the close vote queue, "wrong" audits are the rule.   This is in contrast to my experience in the other queues.  I wonder if I should file a bug report on that....

Comment: Reviews are broken basically.

Comment: @Loko They're not broken. They're just not perfect. If you expect perfection is all systems you'll probably end up very disappointed.

Comment: @AnubianNoob They are broken. Audit questions should be chosen by humans and should be reasonably obvious to a non-robot. Instead they seem designed to trip you up, i.e. to demand perfection themselves. I've given up.

Comment: Well, I now get banned for a week at a time because of the accumulated history, over a period now of years, of these events. I won't claim that all my failures were the fault of bad audits, but plenty of them were.

Comment: @EJP: Yep, they're designed to trip you up if you're not paying attention. It's how they catch robo-reviewers. Occasionally they're wrong, just like virtually every other automated system. The automated system is *already* using humans to select them by using the voting system to do so, so apparently the *humans* are the ones falling short most of the time (as is the case here).

Comment: @EJP Broken is to imply that they do more harm than good.  That is not the case.  They have problems, and there is certainly room for improvement, but the imperfect audits that we have are *far* better than the system was before we had them.  If you're calling them broken then you must not have spent much time reviewing before audits existed.

Comment: @EJP - The audits do a pretty good job of catching people who approve spam: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294028/please-explain-this-audit , and without them the review system was a complete disaster. We still are cleaning up upvoted spam from the two months or so between when review badges were introduced and audits added. What a mess. However, I think we could significantly improve the system by letting people contest troubling audit cases like the above: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188780/review-audits-and-i-understand-button/188790#188790

Comment: Having triggered this discussion, I just feel compelled to emphasise that I don't think and haven't experienced that audits in general are broken.   The first time one sprung on me, I was delighted: what a great idea.   It's just my unfortunate experience that in the close vote queue, the audits have been wrong.

Comment: @BradLarson I agree, there should be a way to contest. And a better way than doing it here, where my experience so far has been entirely negative. On the audit page I particularly resent being expected to press a  button labelled 'I understand' when I don't.

Comment: Maybe the question wasn't closed because the wider SO community considers it a useful question?

Comment: @EJP I've given up as well. I've reviewed every day a lot. After I got a ban for a month, I didn't want to review anymore.

Comment: @immibis maybe. Or, maybe, it's a usual [Trouble With Popularity](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/01/the-trouble-with-popularity/)

Comment: @gnat Or maybe it's a useful question.

Comment: The question of existence is not one of recommendation. The original question was worded as one of existence and it is an important one, as in the process of standardization the existence of an implementation has an effect. Having worked over the paper, I have had that question before, and to be honest, the proposal for standardization is complex and hard to digest and had wished for a reference implementation to verify the contents of the document. There are quite a few programmers interesting in the evolution of the language for which both the question and answer are very relevant.

Comment: How does the question not fit in http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic bullet 3? You could argue that due to the *still off-topic* item 4, but the question does not ask for a recommendation, and item 5 applies: *Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming.* Clearly a compiler is used primarily for programming, is it not?

Comment: This answer is 100% incorrect. I'm sad to see so many upvotes on it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit votes up on this answer indicate that question is not appropriate as an audit. If you want to protect questions like this from meta efffect, it's easy. Just vote close and immediately revert. Or vote down-edit-retract. This will prevent it from becoming a [close/reopen audit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/168372/165773)

Comment: @Servy I did indeed spend a lot of time reviewing before the audits existed, so there is something wrong with your logic. I consider the present system an insult to the intelligence frankly.

Comment: @gnat: There are downvotes too. And, anyway, just because something's popular doesn't mean it's right. You know that. Just look at _any_ of those 300-score "what is your favourite funny programming comment" questions that have been closed and locked for evidence.

Answer (score 27):

I can't quite put my finger on *why*, but I don't feel that this is quite off-topic for the reason you gave.

On the surface of it, yes, the OP is asking for a tool. Well, he's asking whether one exists, which is kind of the same thing.

But under the surface, the status of implementations of language standards *is* academically interesting and fits with other C++ questions on Stack Overflow. It's not a "please tell me your favourite text editor" question. It's more esoteric, it's entirely objective, and it's non-trivial (determining what pieces of what language standards are supported by various compilers and in what ways is really a task unto itself). **That the OP is not asking for a "recommendation" is, I think, the key.**

Anyway, I'm not entirely convinced by this even myself but, if it *were* the case, then the off-topic reason text would be more at fault than you. There are always grey areas and if this is one of them then an itemised list of huge categories of things is misleading.

If anything, my problem with the linked question is that it has a very short shelf-life. It may be off-topic for that reason, but we did away with "too localised" ages ago so I'm not entirely sure *how*.

Either way, it may be more productive to stick to the point when you find yourself in this situation, rather than sort of feeling sorry for yourself and threatening to stop reviewing altogether, just because you didn't understand where to draw the line with one, specific question.

Comment: I agree with everything here.  As a totally separate topic, I personally think that "does such a resource exist" questions would be a very useful addition to our repository of helpful information, despite the short shelf life.  That said, the rules simply rule them out. I think it's a positive thing that we [don't slavishly follow the rules](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30295085/554807) for closure. I do think it's a shame audits fall victim to this. What prompted this question was the comment by a senior SOer that I quoted, which I found while checking here whether I really should have failed.

Comment: Completely agree, but chances are that this is hard to grasp by people outside of the C++ community, and the users that closed it are clearly alien to this community, adding all 5, they total the vast amount of 19 rep points on the C++ tag. Man, I had more than that the first day in SO!

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: That's why I think these people piling upvotes on Stijn and getting uppity about how it's "explicitly off-topic" (including the OP here, threatening to quit reviewing if people don't start agreeing with him on everything) should take a moment to consider whether they really know what they're talking about. :-)

Comment: Well, the first revision *was* a recommendation-question, though I would have left it open anyway because of the self-answer, and because I'm reasonably certain there aren't that many possible answers. Cannot find a reason to close the current version though...

Comment: Sounds like a great analysis. But in my opinion, a question that is so borderline should still not be an audit. Audits should be clear cut cases where one decision is "right", and the other one "wrong".

Comment: @RetoKoradi: I agree.

Answer (score 7):

Different questions (with different levels of relevance):

[C++11 Compiler: Closest to the standard and how close?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7232878/c11-compiler-closest-to-the-standard-and-how-close)

[Compilers that support C11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9804594/compilers-that-support-c11)

[C++11 compiler for windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7966489/c11-compiler-for-windows)

[c++ compiler not installed on this system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25659002/c-compiler-not-installed-on-this-system)

[How to install the GNU Fortran 77 compiler or g77 on Ubuntu 14.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28068148/how-to-install-the-gnu-fortran-77-compiler-or-g77-on-ubuntu-14-04)

[How to install a compiler on Windows? (For a Matlab program)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861605/how-to-install-a-compiler-on-windows-for-a-matlab-program)

[How to install cross compiler (on ubuntu 12.04 LTS) for microprocessor SA1100?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14921463/how-to-install-cross-compiler-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-for-microprocessor-sa1100)

[Is it possible to install a C# compiler without Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861384/is-it-possible-to-install-a-c-sharp-compiler-without-visual-studio)

[Install any version of ruby with RVM on mavericks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19594719/install-any-version-of-ruby-with-rvm-on-mavericks)

[PHP Interpreter is not Installed (Linux)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21212824/php-interpreter-is-not-installed-linux)

[How to install Python interpreters on Linux in a fully automated way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10870401/how-to-install-python-interpreters-on-linux-in-a-fully-automated-way)

All those questions share the same theme: How do I get a tool that provides *X* in my system.  Are all those questions to be closed?

Since you brought the issue, how is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20831410/36565) of yours not *recommending a tutorial*?

I look at the rules in the site, I read them and I get an understanding of the spirit: this is not a place to be asking for recommendations or to have others do your research work, but having been there before a couple of months back and not managing to get an implementation of Concepts TS up and running, I do find the question and answer extremely valuable.

An important note that might not be quite understood by people outside of the C++ community is that this question is not asking for a recommendation for a tool to solve a problem, but for an implementation of a proposed document so that the language itself can be verified.  This was never a question along the lines of: *how can I setup a web server and a wiki and...* but closer to questions asking about where the documentation for a particular feature of the language.

Where the Concepts TS may be ambiguous the reference implementation by the author (the one Dietmar talks about in the answer) is the complement to show the *intent* of the author.  The intention at this point, where there are no production compilers with support for the feature, is to help tailor the document that will become standard, remove ambiguities... Where there multiple implementations, the ability to compare the results would lead to requests to improve the wording of the document to clarify intentions.

The question is quite *niche* and I understand that it can seem as *what is the best web server* type of questions, that is the main reason for the comment I added in the original question.  This is *not* what it may seem if you are unaware of the standardization process.

Even if it is literally asking for (the existence of) a tool, and by the letter it is against the guidelines, this is a *guide dogs* that I strongly believe should be allowed where pets are not.

Comment: Checking some of these links they seem to fall in the exception category: they are questions about tooling directly related to programming and as such perfectly fine.

Comment: @Gimby: How is a compiler *not* related to programming? What else can it be used for? The original question was asking for a compiler that supported a proposed extension to the language.

Comment: I think it behooves "the special people in the C++ community" to take care when asking questions to make sure that they don't appear to anyone except "one of your own" to be "asking to find a tool".   The [question that I know @DavidRodríguez-dribeas cares a lot about)[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30290240) is a great example. Its original working rang all the alarm bells for the dedicated folk in the CVQ.   With due flagging, it was adjusted and continues open as a guide dog.   This is how it should be.   It doesn't make it "on topic".  It makes it "a worthwhile exception".

Comment: There is another problem with this to be aware of - directly related to my question.   Once this guide dog question stays open, it becomes a candidate for an CVQ audit test.  Then some unsuspecting tired CVQ auditer gets it as a test and says "close" because on the face if it that is right.... then they fail.    This exact thing is what led to my question here: grey-zone/guide dog questions appearing as audit tests.   It's a problem.

Comment: @GreenAsJade: Should all of the linked questions here be closed? Why/why not?

Comment: You can probably find a close reason for most, if anything there is a bit of a lack of personal research in most of them. Take this one as an example: any answer would very quickly become outdated, it is better answered by Google or Wikipedia. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9804594/compilers-that-support-c11 . I think the disputed question as it stands now has a similar problem, but I see the value in the remainder information contained within so I'm glad it won't ever be auto-deleted given that it is answered and upvoted.

Comment: I found this to be a fascinating set of questions that highlight that the guidelines should probably make specific allowance for discussing what compilers/interpretters support what language features.   I think that pedants could go attack those questions with close votes, but I hope that the CVQ reviewers would have the sense to knock them back.

Answer (score -12):

> How is this not "asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource"? .... which is explicitly off-topic.

I think this targets questions asking for a good ... or not giving objective criteria. Here, the criterion is explicit and objective.

So I'm not sure the best option is to close the question, even if it seems to fall under this close reason.

Comment: **Moderator notice**: Extended discussion can be taken to chat; I've moved these to [a chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78444/discussion-on-answer-by-eric-levieil-should-i-avoid-reviewing-altogether).

Answer (score -25):

It's OK if you failed the Nth audit. Some things we get straight in the first attempts, some things take a few attempts, and some take really longer. So, until you become REALLY un-interested - give it few tries.

There are some contradicting scenarios, and not everyone see it, but that doesn't mean that you are only one to see it that way.