# Why was this audit question "irredeemable"?

Tags: discussion

An answer to this question came up as an audit in the low quality queue: [jQuery Smooth Scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10556183/jquery-smooth-scrolling/43861166#43861166). Nothing in the response strikes me as "offensive or repulsive rather than helpful"; my best guess is that the link inside it caused it to be marked as spam.

This wouldn't be the first audit question marked as spam because of its link—it's been discussed on Meta [before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294028/please-explain-this-audit). Still, I saw nothing offensive in the content of the link. It struck me as simply the good practice of citing sources. What am I missing?

EDIT: [Link to audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/16212255).

Comment: Oh awesome.  I still can't see the deleted answer even in the audit link.

Comment: Pretty sure you need >10k rep to view deleted answers.

Comment: @aryamccarthy for some reason I thought audits were exempt from that 10k limit, but maybe I'm mistaken.  Also, sometimes other 10k users provide a (link to) a screenshot.

Comment: seems to be another auto-selected audit, generated due to a mod deleting it. I don't see any evidence of it being self promotion (but i also haven't followed the link), so no idea. there's probably more going on behind the scenes in this case than we can see.

Comment: I'd really appreciate some clarification—this was the tipping-point question that locked me out of review queues.

Comment: i mean.. the answer is certainly downvote worthy, it doesn't go into what's wrong with the OP's code and instead just presents another solution with no explanation. that could be why it was deleted too.

Comment: Right—though I would figure there's a difference between DVing and deleting as "offensive or repulsive".

Comment: iirc that user has been spamming that blog on various answers. I may be wrong, but it's familiar. Maybe Smokedetector reported it. Let me see

Comment: where are you getting that wording from? "offensive or repulsive" not quite sure what that has to do with this. those aren't the only reasons answers get deleted.

Comment: @KevinB The text of the audit message was "STOP! Look and Listen. This was an audit...It is abusive, nonsense, noise, spam, blatantly off-topic, or otherwise irredeemable — readers will find it **offensive or repulsive** rather than helpful..." (Emphasis added.)

Comment: There is at least [this older link only answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11011317/wordpress-plugin-works-only-for-logged-users/42856417#42856417) which got deleted. So overall I'd guess it was all marked as spam, and that made it an audit.

Comment: @Bart I don't have enough rep to see the deleted answer. Does this mean the audit is well-posed?

Comment: I'd go for "no", as in, it's not a great answer at all, it's poor. But to assume you should have seen that as obvious spam ... nah. If you interpret it as "This is the code, and here is where I got it", I can forgive you for that. It's the side-effect of an automatic system which selects cases it thinks are suitable audit examples.

Comment: @Bart Thanks for the clarity—agreed that it's a poor answer. Does that forgiveness come in the form of lifting the review lock?

Comment: That's not up to me. I only have a smiting stick, and unfortunately that does not come with the power to lift any such bans/locks. So you'll have to wait for one of those people with a diamond to come along. ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The author had spammed that answer on a bunch of questions, and hit even more questions with similar links to that website. I've no idea if it was his site, or if he was just hoping to farm it for other people's code in an attempt to game *this* site, but either way it's pretty dirty.

...That said, none of this is visible in the audit. I've lifted the block on your account.